# Determine Vector Spaces and Subspaces for Two Sides

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a question which consists on two parts.

If we want to find that the given vectors are in a specific vector space or not? We can find it through various methods. Like we can find it through determinant method or through converting the vectors in equations of linear system then by converting to augmented matrix and so on...
Now my question is that how to find that the vectors on two sides i.e., L.H.S and R.H.S are equal or not?
LET SAY:
Required:

a)  Prove or disprove that in $\mathbb{R^3}$, 
$$span  \begin{Bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
    1  \\
    5  \\
    6  \\
   \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
    5  \\
    6  \\
    7 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}\end{Bmatrix} \begin{matrix}\end{matrix}= span\begin{Bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
    2  \\
    -3  \\
    -3  \\
   \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
    2  \\
    5  \\
    7  \\ 
\end{pmatrix}\end{Bmatrix} \begin{matrix}\end{matrix}$$

**My Attempt:**

What I have done is, taken the L.H.S extracted the relevant planes from vectors, made the Linear system, then converted the system into augmented form, reduced the matrix to row echelon form by applying Elementary Row Operations, again extracted the Linear system from Row Echelon form, only to know that the system is in-consistent because third equation in the system is has a 0 on the left side and has non-zero value at right side, hence our L.H.S's set does not span the vector space. Same I did with the R.H.S only to know the details. I am writing below in Mathematical form after solving the system of linear equations for both L.H.S and R.H.S 
we get following reduced echelon form respectively:

$$ L.H.S= \left[
\begin{array}{cc|ccc}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 7/23 & -6/23\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & -2/23 & 5/23\\
    0 & 0 & 1 &  3/23 & -19/23\\
\end{array}
\right] $$
and 
$$ R.H.S= \left[
\begin{array}{cc|ccc}
    1 & 0 & 0 & -7/6 & 5/6\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & -1/2 & 1/2\\
    0 & 0 & 1 &  10/3 & -8/3\\
\end{array}
\right] $$

Now kindly tell me that what I have done is correct or not? It has been proved or disproved that the :
$$span  \begin{Bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
    1  \\
    5  \\
    6  \\
   \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
    5  \\
    6  \\
    7\\ 
\end{pmatrix}\end{Bmatrix} \begin{matrix}\end{matrix}= span\begin{Bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
    2  \\
    -3  \\
    -3  \\
   \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
    2  \\
    5  \\
    7  \\ 
\end{pmatrix}\end{Bmatrix} \begin{matrix}\end{matrix}?$$

Second question is related to above question.

**b)** Find all the subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$, if possible.

I'm totally confused in this question. I'm not getting the idea that what I have to do ...

Your Explanation will be highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: for b) are you asking for the subspaces in R or $R^3$?

Comment: @gimusi I'm asking for the subspaces in R.

Comment: @RashidMahmood ok then you can refer to my answer

Comment: @amWhy My attempt regarding above mentioned questions has been added.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Rahshid.  I have removed my delete vote, and will also initiate the possible reopening (but it will take four others to join me) in hopes it is reopened.

Comment: @Learner If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For a)** you can verify whether the two subspaces have the same dimension and then use a geometric argument finding the equation of the planes/lines which describe them. In particular you can compare the **direction vector** in case of lines and the **normal vector** in case of planes.

Namely in this case it easy to verify that the dimension for both subspaces is 2. The normal vectors which describe the two planes are:

$$n_1=\begin{vmatrix}
i&j&k\\0&4&1\\1&2&3
\end{vmatrix}=10i+1j+-4k$$

$$n_2=\begin{vmatrix}
i&j&k\\1&-2&-2\\1&4&6
\end{vmatrix}=-4i-8j+6k$$

Since $n_1$ and $n_2$ are linearly independent the two subspace describe different planes.

**For b)** if you think to the definition of subspace the only possibility are the origin and all $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: **For a)** After solving the both sides individually, I came to know that the system of linear equations for both sides are inconsistent. So, consequently both sides do not span the space.
SO, I would like to ask that can I say that span {(0,4,1),(1,2,3)}=span{(1,-2,-2),(1,4,6)} ?

Comment: @RashidMahmood Yes also a simply check by cross product shows that they describe 2 different planes thus the span are different.

Comment: So, it has been proved that span {(0,4,1),(1,2,3)} is equal to span {(1,-2,-2),(1,4,6)} ???

Comment: @RashidMahmood No they are different because they span two different planes.

Comment: THANKS! 
**For b)** This is enough to say that "the only possibility are the origin and all R." ??? or we have to describe anything else?

Comment: Kindly tell me @gimusi what I have asked in my above comment.

Comment: @RashidMahmood Sorry, I lost your previous comment. Yes it is sufficient and it is an argument valid in general. In $R^3$ for example they are the origin, lines through origin, planes through origin and all $R^3$

Comment: Again Thanks for your response @gumsi. Could you provide me some details regarding above argument about R?

Comment: @RashidMahmood Which one? this last on the possible subspaces?

Comment: Details or reasons regarding this @gimusi : "For b) if you think to the definition of subspace the only possibility are the origin and all $\mathbb{R}$."

Comment: @RashidMahmood In $\mathbb{R}$ the possible subspaces may have dimension 0 or 1. The origin must always be included in a subspace thus we have the origin with dim=0 (which also satisfy the other 2 properties). For dim=1 you need a basis vector which obviously span all $\mathbb{R}$ and satisfy the requested properties.

Comment: Got it. Thanks @gimusi